# passing localStorage data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to view and manipulate Javascript localStorage information on a PHP page using PHP. I have gotten pretty far with this, but I'm not where I need to be. I'm using PHP 7.3 and vanilla JS.

I have AJAX POSTing the data to a PHP processing page (not the one that calls the javascript function). However, I need to access the POST variable on the page that called the javascript. How can I pass the information back without a click?

The page wishlist.php contains a link to the js file and `<div id="temporary_wishlist"></div>`.

Javascript called from wishlist.php:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  loadWishlist();
});

// get wishlist contents
function loadWishlist() {
  var items = wishlistStorage.data.items.join("%20");
  var item_notes = wishlistStorage.data.item_notes.join("%20");
  var comments = wishlistStorage.data.comments;
  var wishlistRequest;
  var response = null;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    wishlistRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    wishlistRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  wishlistRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(wishlistRequest.readyState == 4 && wishlistRequest.status == 200) {
      response = wishlistRequest.responseText;
      document.getElementById("temporary_wishlist").innerHTML = response;
    }
  }
  wishlistRequest.open("POST", "/wishlist-processor.php", true);
  wishlistRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  wishlistRequest.send("wishlist_items=" + encodeURIComponent(items) 
    + "&wishlist_itemnotes=" + encodeURIComponent(item_notes)
    + "&wishlist_comments=" + encodeURIComponent(comments));
}
```

Given the above, I have access to `$_POST['wishlist_items']` inside `wishlist-processor.php`. Whatever I output inside of `wishlist-processor.php` is visible to the visitor on wishlist.php inside `<div id="temporary_wishlist"></div>`. It is not, however, visible in the Console.

On `wishlist.php`, I want to load the information into a PHP variable so I can send it to a MySQL query. If I could just POST to self like I do with form validation I would have access to `$_POST['wishlist_items']` from wishlist.php. I already tried setting the URL in the `open("POST", URL, true)` function to `_self` or `wishlist.php`, and that didn't work for me.

I know it's suggested that I use Fetch, but I'm already overwhelmed learning new things I want to understand AJAX better. Also, Fetch doesn't work on Firefox Android.

Comment: You shouldn't use `%20` if you're calling `encodeURIComponent()`. That's an encoded space, and you'll encode it twice.

Comment: But other than that, this code should work. The values should be in the `$_POST` variables.

Comment: I don't follow. "It is not, however, visible in the Console." -> what do you mean, the browser console? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your data seems to be in the `response` variable.

Comment: Barmar and Jeto — Thank you. I'm not seeing encoding problems. %20 seems to pass through OK. You are both correct; however, I only have access to the POST at `wishlist-processor.php`. My need access to it from `wishlist.php.`

Comment: _"Fetch doesn't work on Firefox Android"_ according to this, it has been supported since v68 ~ https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Comment: You will have access to `$_POST` data in any script that handles a POST request. At the moment, you are only posting to `wishlist-processor.php` via AJAX. It's not clear how you want data to flow through your application but I suspect you have a misunderstanding about how HTTP requests interact with your scripts. Could you please clarify what you want to happen at each stage in your app's lifecycle?

Comment: Thank you Phil. I guess MDN needs to update their compatibility table. Anyway, with regard to AJAX, `var_dump($_POST)` from wishlist.php gives me `array(0) { }` whereas the same function from wishlist-processor.php gives me a `array(3)` populated with my data. So it doesn't appear that I have access to `$_POST` anywhere except for the destination page in the AJAX call. Hence, the problem.

Comment: Perhaps I have poorly explained the problem... I don't know if this is any better but here goes... I have a PHP page on which I would like to display and manipulate data from localStorage when a visitor lands on it. I can grab the data using JS, but the only way I know to hand it over to PHP is by sending it to some other page. Then I have to find a way to send the data back to the original page.

Comment: Also, note that I am already able to view the data on the original page as described in the question. It is visible in the destination div, but not in the console. I do not know how to access the information in PHP on the original page from this state. That's my goal.

Comment: I am currently working around the problem by doing my MySQL queries at wishlist-processor.php. The visitor will be able to see the results through the AJAX window. I was hoping to avoid having to manage separate pages, but it looks like this is how it's going to be.